# Resolving a Node of a Plane Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, singularity-theory

In the book Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces, Miranda explains how to resolve the node of a plane curve by plugging the hole at the node using hole charts. The idea is at a node $p$, the surface $X$ is the locus of $gh$, we delete $p$ from $X$ so that $X \setminus \{p\}$ is the union of $X_g \setminus \{p\}$ and $X_h \setminus \{p\}$. We now have two hole charts at $X_g$ and $X_h$ and we resolve the node at $p$ by plugging in these two hole charts.

My question is how is the surface that we get after plugging in the hole charts Hausdorff? This construction looks to me like the line with 2 origins.

Comment: You're visualizing this incorrectly. The node looks like $xy=0$, and after performing the construction described by Miranda you get something that looks more like $xy=1$ (not literally; what actually happens looks like deleting the intersection point, "pulling the lines apart", and *then* taking the closure so that you get two distinct points added in).

Comment: I've thought about this , for example, visualizing resolving $xy=0$ on the real plane by pulling the two lines apart into 3 dimensional space. But then this disconnects the surface no? But if the surface is (somehow) still connected, I don't see how to separate the two new points added...

Comment: This is just a local picture. The pieces connect up at infinity.

Comment: OK this clears my question somewhat, though there seems to be some highly non-trivial analysis going on. I think this construction is described in greater detail in Chapter 2 of Griffiths' "Introduction to Algebraic Curves". I just wish that Miranda gave a disclaimer like "hey, btw I'm doing some heavy lifting here..."